# HTML Email Template from Lead Email Activity Tab in Lightning

Tags: lightning, email-template, html

In Salesforce classic, you can choose your HTML email templates from the "Send Email" in the Activity related list.

In Lightning, can you pick an HTML email template created in Lightning from Activity?  It seems like we can only create text versions.

For example, from the Lead record — I want to send Lead an HTML email.  So I try to pick a template but can not access any of the HTML templates I created in the lightning.  Is this not available?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

The new Lightning Email feature use of templates from Set Up are now with processes and rules only, not for selection from records as is the case with Classic.

Answer (score 0):

They are now available to use in lightning - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=classic_templates_in_lightning.htm&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com.au%2F&type=5

[image]